# why can i insert string value into int column in python sqlite database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

i run following codes in python3:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
conn.execute("create table if not exists data(\
              id int prinmary key,view int)")
conn.execute("insert into data (id,view) values (0,0)")
conn.execute("insert into data (id,view) values (1,'--')")
print(conn.execute("select * from data order by id").fetchall())
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

and no error occured, "[(0, 0), (1, '--')]" was printed, why?

Comment: SQLite has dynamic typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented as a feature in SQLite documentation, is is even documented is its [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3):

> (3) SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!
>
> This is a feature, not a bug. SQLite uses dynamic typing. It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column...

Answer (score -1):

From the sqlite page:
INSERT INTO table1 (
 column1,
 column2 ,..)
VALUES
 (
 value1,
 value2 ,...);

After insert into data, you would need to tell it into which fields.